# Check if value exists in enum

Tags: go

I have created a strict like the following in my app:

```
type Datatype int8

const (
    user Datatype = iota
    address
    test
)

var datatypes = [...]string{"User", "Address", "Test"}

func (datatype Datatype) String() string {
    return datatypes[datatype]
}
```

I would like to be able to validate a value passed via a *command-line* flag against this enum.

I thought I had seen something like `dtype == Datatype` being used, but I am apparently sorely mistaken.

If this is not possible I can go the route of putting these values in an array. However, I feel the enum approach is more elegant.

Comment: Can you clarify "validate a value passed via a command-line flag against this enum"?  Are you trying to see if a flag was passed on the command line?  Validate user input?  Check for non-default values in a struct?

Comment: In addition to the above .. can you please show us this "struct" you're referring to? How does a struct come into play here? ... Are you sure you're not just looking for a map?

Comment: I was trying to do exactly what @IanNaN answered below. Thank you maerics and Simon I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code sample it looks like you are trying to see if a map (rather than a struct) contains a particular key.

If so, the answer is [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

> A two-value assignment tests for the existence of a key:
>
> ```
> i, ok := m["route"]
> ```
>
> In this statement, the first value (i) is assigned
>   the value stored under the key "route". If that key doesn't exist, i
>   is the value type's zero value (0). The second value (ok) is a bool
>   that is true if the key exists in the map, and false if not.
>
> To test for a key without retrieving the value, use an underscore in
>   place of the first value:
>
> ```
> _, ok := m["route"]
> ```